# how to set border spacing in javafx

Tags: css, javafx, border-spacing

how to use **border spacing property** in javafx ?

Like in css for html

```
table.ex1 {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}
```

How do i use border spacing in javafx?

Inside a TabPane wherer i want to put a bottom border under each tab and my css is

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-width: 4px;
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;


}
```

its working and i have nice bottom border but i need some more border spacing , so someone please tell me how to do that ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain, "but i need some more border spacing"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tab:top{
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-border-insets: 0 0 0 0;
-fx-border-color: white white white white ; 
-fx-padding: 15px;
}
```

I think there is no border-spacing type property in javafx css but anyway you can do it in TabPane by -fx-padding property for tab.

Answer (score 0):

Add some `-fx-border-insets`. Something like

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-width: 4px, 0px;
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent white transparent, transparent;
    -fx-border-insets: 0px 0px 2px 0px, 0px 0px 4px 0px ;

}
```

Check the [CSS documentation for `Region`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) for details.